# Can ZeroMQ be used to accept traditional socket requests?

Tags: sockets, tcp, zeromq, nettcpbinding

I'm trying to re-write one of our old Servers using ZeroMQ, for now I have the following Server setup, (which works for Zmq requests):

```
    using (var context = ZmqContext.Create())
    using (var server = context.CreateSocket(SocketType.REP)) {
        server.Bind("tcp://x.x.x.x:5705");

        while (true) { ... }
```

This kind of setup works fine if I use the Zmq client library to connect `context.CreateSocket(SocketType.REQ)`

But unfortunately we've got a lot of legacy code that needs to connect to this server and the sockets are created using .net socket libs:

```
    Socket = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    Socket.Connect(ipAddress, port);
```

Is there a way to write a ZeroMQ Server to accept these traditional .net socket connections?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can achieve this using [ZMQ_STREAM sockets](http://api.zeromq.org/4-0:zmq-socket#toc19).

Please note that since zeroMQ 4.x, the RAW router option [has been deprecated](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.network.zeromq.devel/19547) for a new ZMQ_STREAM socket type, that works the same way as ROUTER + RAW.

It seems it is bound to evolve, though.

I recently tried ZMQ_STREAM sockets in version 4.0.1.

You can open one, use `zmq_rcv` until you receive the whole message (you have to check it is whole yourself), or `zmq_msg_rcv` to let ZeroMQ handle it. You will receive an *identifier* message part, just like the *identifier* you would find in `ROUTER` sockets, directly followed by one **ONLY** *body* part. There is no empty delimiter between them like there would be using a `REQ` Socket talking to a `ROUTER` Socket. So if you route them, be sure to add it yourself.

Beware though: if there is latency on the other end or if your message exceeds ZeroMQ `ZMQ_STREAM` buffers (mine are 8192 bytes long), your message can be interpreted by zeroMQ as a series of messages.

In that case, you will receive as many different ZeroMQ messages including *both* the identifier part **and** the body part, and it is your job to aggregate them, knowing that if several clients are talking to the `STREAM` socket, they might get mixed up. I personnally use a hash table using the binary identifier as a key, and delete the entry from the table when I know the message is complete and sent to the next node.

Sending through a `ZMQ_STREAM` with `zmq_msg_send` or `zmq_send` works fine as is.

Answer (score 4):

You probably have to use zmq's RAW socket type (instead of REP) to connect with and read client data without zmq-specific framing.

**HTTP Server in C (from Pieter's blog)**
http://hintjens.com/blog:42

**RAW Socket type info**
https://github.com/hintjens/libzmq/commit/777c38ae32a5d1799b3275d38ff8d587c885dd55

Comment: Hey @Raffian, thanks, but not sure how to implement this.  There is no SocketType of RAW, do you have an example you could provide?

Comment: Yes, here's one Pieter wrote, http://hintjens.com/blog:42, it's basically a HTTP server using zmq raw sockets, it's in C, but you should be able to port it to .net, as long as .net it supports `RAW` socket, I know the pure Java zmq library (jeromq) does not...hope it helps.

Comment: Thank @Raffian, I can't link directly to the ZMQ lib, I'm using clrzmq, the .Net implementation so this may not be possible then